# Regex for match following strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to regex I want to create regex for following

AL--->**accepted**
AL100--->**accepted**
100---->**accepted**
100L--->**Rejected**
AL1122--->**accepted**
AL1224K-->**rejected**

Means either its AL or AL with numbers or only numbers

Below is my Regex which I have written but it's not working

```
^AL[0-9]+$|AL
```

Please Help

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just slightly modify the regex you already have to this:

```
^AL[0-9]*$
```

This will match `AL` in isolation (no digits), or followed by any number of digits, but nothing else.

**Demo:**

```
/^AL[0-9]*$/.test('AL1224K');
false

/^AL[0-9]*$/.test('AL1224');
true
```

**Update:**

If you also want to accept pure numbers, then you can modify your regex by making the leading `AL` optional:

```
^(AL)?[0-9]*$
```

E.g.

```
/^(AL)?[0-9]*$/.test('AL1224')
true
/^(AL)?[0-9]*$/.test('1224')
true
```

Comment: Hey what if i have to make number also to be expected /^AL[0-9]*$/.test('100');

Comment: If an empty string is not expected, use `^(AL[0-9]*|[0-9]+)$`